# Looking for a standard way to execute "npm run build" in every folder beneath some root

Tags: npm, create-react-app

Is there a some simple way I can search through all the package.json files in a folder on my macbook and run the commands "npm init" and "npm run build" in every child folder? I want to check if any of my folders in a folder hierarchy will fail to build.